# JS Library for object compression

Tags: javascript, compression

Most compression libraries assume data packages should hold all the data needed to decompress them (zip, BiSON etc...).

In the project I'm currently working on, I always send the same type of packages. Ex `{"x":100,"y":101,"z":102}`

Right now, I manually create my own compression system that will transform the above into `[100,101,102]` and then use a standard binary compression library to convert it to something like `&($#S`.

The goal here is to not provide the keys/properties of the objects as they will always be the same.

While this works, maintaining this system for object with dozens of properties (each being possibly an object or array) can become an issue.

Is there a library that compresses/decompresses an JS object into/from a C-like struct?

Ex:

```
var schema = Library({x:Number,y:Number,z:Number});
var compress = schema.compress({x:1,y:1,z:1});
console.log(schema.decompress(compress)); //{x:1,y:1,z:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating my own library for that...

https://github.com/rainingchain/schema-encoder